# Delete both row and column in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have an array like this:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
    [4, 5, 6]
    [7, 8, 9]
```

And I want to delete both the ith row and column. So if i=1, I'd create (with 0-indexing):

```
[1, 3]
[7, 9]
```

Is there an easy way of doing this with a one-liner? I know I can call `np.delete()` twice, but that seems a little unclean.

It'd be exactly equivalent to `np.delete(np.delete(x, idx, 0), idx, 1)`, where idx is the index of the row/column pair to delete - it'd just look cleaner.

Comment: Do you want to delete a row and a column with a single index? or one for each?

Comment: Ultimately all deletes come down to selecting certain elements or rows/columns. You are making a new array, not changing the original.

Comment: @Chris Ideally, I'd just use a single index.

Comment: What is the rule that tells you which row and column to remove? Is the array always square? Are you always removing a row and column with the same index? What purpose is served by doing this?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Given an index, delete that row/column. The matrix is always square. For my use case I'm removing a row and column with the same index, but something in more general form is fine. 

My use case is a little complicated. Essentially I need to do this to extract a particular row/column pair in a matrix, while keeping the new matrix square. I realize that `np.delete(np.delete(x, idx, 0), idx, 1)` is an easy solution, I just feel like there should be a cleaner way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [196]: x = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
```

If you look at `np.delete` code, you'll see that it's python (not compiled) and takes different approaches depending on how the delete values are specified.  One is to make a `res` array of right size, and copy two slices to it.

Another is to make a boolean mask.  For example:

```
In [197]: mask = np.ones(x.shape[0], bool)
In [198]: mask[1] = 0
In [199]: mask
Out[199]: array([ True, False,  True])
```

Since you are deleting the same row and column, use this indexing:

```
In [200]: x[mask,:][:,mask]
Out[200]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [7, 9]])
```

A 1d boolean mask like this can't be 'broadcasted' in the same ways a integer array can.

We can do the 2d advanced indexing with:

```
In [201]: idx = np.nonzero(mask)[0]
In [202]: idx
Out[202]: array([0, 2])
In [203]: np.ix_(idx,idx)
Out[203]: 
(array([[0],
        [2]]),
 array([[0, 2]]))
In [204]: x[np.ix_(idx,idx)]
Out[204]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [7, 9]])
```

Actually `ix_` can work directly from the boolean array(s):

```
In [207]: np.ix_(mask,mask)
Out[207]: 
(array([[0],
        [2]]),
 array([[0, 2]]))
```

This isn't a one-liner, but it probably is faster than the double `delete`, since it strips off all the extra baggage that the more general function requires.

Answer (score 3):

This can be easily achieved by numpy's `delete` function. It would be:

```
arr = np.delete(arr, index, 0) # deletes the desired row 
arr = np.delete(arr, index, 1) # deletes the desired column at index
```

The third argument is the `axis`.